# Sorting by length of array, if it's not filled in the model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, i have two mongoose models:

```
User: {
   name: String,
   ..........
   locations: []
}

Location: {
   title: String,
   .............
   owner: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
   }
}
```

my lookup function in node, for User is something like:

```
api.find = function(filter, sort, skip, limit){
    var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
    filter = treatFilter(filter);
    sort = treatSort(sort);
    if(callback && typeof callback === 'function'){
        User.find(filter).sort(sort).skip(skip).limit(limit).exec(function(err, users){
            if(users.length === 0){
                callback(err, users);
            }
            for(var i = 0, complete = 0; i < users.length; i++){
                (function(idx){
                    var user = users[idx];
                    var id = user.id;
                    Location.find({owner: id}, function(err, locations){
                        user.locations = locations;
                        if(++complete === users.length){
                            callback(err, users);
                        }
                    });
                })(i);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

what would my `sort` object have to be like so i could sort by number of locations?

Thanks, if you have any doubts i will be happy to explain my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this post ([mongoose - sort by array length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604075/mongoose-sort-by-array-length))

You have to maintain a separate field that stores the location count -- not too much overhead but a little annoying to maintain

I looked into sorting by a virtual field, but this too is impossible and probably would be quite inefficient...

Comment: hmm, thanks. I thought of that but it is waaaay to annoying to mantain. I will accept your answer if none better will come by

Comment: There is no better way. Since you're using mongoose, you can just re-count the array prior to saving using middleware. It's not a big deal, really.